# Colouring a DC.JS GeoChloropleth Map based on value

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, choropleth

I have a map build with `dc.js` and `crossfilter`. I am trying to colour the map, but I just can't get my head around why it isn't working. I have created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a0jqgh1q/1/) of where I am at.

The CSV file driving the data has the following structure:

```
ccgcode,ccgname,metric,sex,life
06M,Great Yarmouth And Waveney,3,M,70
05G,North Staffordshire,3,M,63
... etc.
```

The way I would like the colouring to work is like so:

- metric = 1 then colour is `#7CBD30`
- metric = 2 then colour is `#0066CC`
- metric = 3 then colour is `#EE2E11` (*should be red*)

In other words, the colour is conditional and is dependent on the metric value of the CCG (see CSV above).

I am able to get this working in pure D3, but not with `dc.js`.

Comment: You're data doesn't produce 'q3-3', it only produces 'q1-3' & 'q2-3'

Comment: But when I build this in D3 alone with same data, it does produce `q3-3` :(

Comment: Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b7hyd9rh/) proving that it works with `D3` alone. That uses `TopoJSON` instead of `GeoJSON`, but that shouldn't matter for the purpose of colouring correct?

Comment: Look at the console logs in both of these : https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/b7hyd9rh/1/ , https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/a0jqgh1q/2/ the second one (the one that doesnt work) doesn't output q3-3 at all

Comment: I don't doubt that, I have also checked the console previously, but my question is why doesn't it? They both use the same `quantize` scale, with the same domain and range!

Comment: Yeah they are the same but looks like the data your passing to it is different. Once passes 1,2,3 and the other only 1,2, still trying to figure out why

Comment: Theres your problem. https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/a0jqgh1q/3/ , https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/b7hyd9rh/2/ the data is different. In the one that works you have more data, in the one that doesnt you have less. Check console logs of links i have sent. Go from there :) I would try do it myself but I'm busy for the next couple of hours :)

Comment: How does one show console on JSFiddle [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/sthag/MWadX/)? I'm not too familiar with JSFiddle

Comment: Try this link : https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/4rm7zzwx/ something was up with yours and it had firebug opening automatically. Im not sure why. Just right click anywhere and click inspect then go to console. Or just click Ctrl + Shift + I